# how to get File Name and File Size in WebAPI controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC 4 and webAPI and need to upload a image using file upload control.
I need to know the replacement for the following in WebAPI:

```
int filelength = Request.Files[0].ContentLength;
byte[] databytes = new byte[filelength];
Request.Files[0].InputStream.Read(databytes, 0, filelength);
string filename = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[0].FileName);
```

I mean I need to get the file name and file size in WebAPI controller.

Any alternatives for `Request.Files`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [HttpPostedFile class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];

    if (file.ContentLength > 0) // file.ContentLength is the file size in bytes
    {
      var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);    
    }
```