# HTTP Headers Check to prevent uploading a too big file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-8

I'd like to know if there is a way  to tell my ASP.NET MVC application to stop servicing a a form post with a file too big, bigger than 10 megabytes in my case.

Are the request headers sent and treated by the application before the client sends the whole content? Should I use a Http Module or an Action Filter? Does any of them kick in before the server has recieved the whole request?

Case in point, if the client tries to upload a 20 Mb file, I want the server to call the upload off as soon as it got the `Content-Length` header. Said validation must be on server-side. Javascript is out because **I still have to service Internet Explorer 6**, so no File API.

**tl;dr**. What I want is being able to respond on server side, as soon as I have received the request headers. Is it possible?

Configuration : Windows Server 2012, IIS 8.0, ASP.NET MVC 5

Comment: You might be able to do this by adding a CSP header. A Content Security Policy header.

Comment: Sorry, Karl, Content Security Policy (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/) would not help in my case.

Comment: Honestly, IE 6 is a decade and half old, I would suggest formally requesting your client/customer/whatever upgrades. Other than that, I know of no client side validation that would allow it, use js or server side validation.

Comment: Server side validation is precisely what I want. I do not want to bother with IE 6 but I am still stuck with it for now because of political choices well beyond my reach. What I want is how do I tell "don't try to send me 20 megabytes" before I get a 20 megabytes request?

Comment: Yeah that's why I said request instead of just "Change it!", usually that stuff is far beyond a devs possible sphere of influence...but it's always worth trying. You want to do server side validation on an object that is not yet on the server? That's not possible. It's either client side validation or bust if you don't want to receive the request.

Comment: IE6 hardly matters, as the File API isn't supported in IE until version 10. While the OP *may* be able to convince the client to drop IE6, IE7-9 still holds far too much marketshare to not support.

Comment: I've never done it, so I'm making this a comment instead of a answer, but you should be able to make an HttpModule that can change the request inbound and then change it to allow MVC to catch/throw the exception.  I don't know if this can be done before the whole file is uploaded (my knowledge says yes, I'm just not 100% sure).

Comment: Can you not use web api? Then use the HttpPostedFile class? HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0]; if (file.contentLength < 10240) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459630/how-to-get-file-name-and-file-size-in-webapi-controller